# Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I want to post some message to fb wall using java code. but while posting got this error: "com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

FacebookType publishMessageResponse =facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("message", postText));

Comment: As the exception states, check your facebook app settings. On Status & Review check for Approved Items...I guess the item you want is 'publish_actions'.

Comment: Are you using the User Access token or Application Access token ? This might also be a cause if your required permissions are approved.